# Ignore or Password going back in android

Tags: android

Im trying to make a proggram that doesnt let mobile in android 4 to go back(for example user in android opened some folders) and for it, android wants you to write a password for it. is it possible? what is the best way for doing that? is there anything in android sdk for it or as android is  "open source" there is anyway to make changes in it.(i have no knowledge about android source code). thanks for  helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to disable back button for your application then use the following code

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //empty 
    }
```

Comment: i want do it in android. not in any proggram. when i wanted to search in my folders and subfolders, if i wanted to go back android asks for a password